# Does QT's QList save iterators after container's modifications?

Tags: qt, iterator

Are the iterators pointed to elements of QList still valid after there are any remove operation from QList?
I need to remove some element from QList, so I store an iterators for those elements to another container and than take this saved iterators and use to remove necessary elements from QList.
It looks like this:

```
// inside a loop for 'list'
QList<type>::iterator it = list.begin() + j;
removing.append(it);
// end of loop for 'list'
```

...

```
while(removing.empty() == false)
{
    list.erase(removing.takeFirst());
}
```

So, when `removing` container contains more than 1 element, app crash occurs (SEGMENTATION FAULT) when attempting to erase second element, whereas first was erased successfully. 
What is the reason and is there any way to remove elements with iterators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for some reason you would like to remove elements from a container in that way then you could try to use QLinkedList instead of QList because `Iterators pointing to an item in a QLinkedList remain valid as long as the item exists, whereas iterators to a QList can become invalid after any insertion or removal.` I copied this quotation from Qt's documentation: [Container Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Using QLinkedList helps and works correct!

Answer (score 1):

No, the iterators will not be valid. If you just want to remove all the elements, use `QList::clear()`. You can call `qDeleteAll()` on the `QList` first if you need to delete the items.

If you want to selectively remove elements using iterators, you can do something like the following. You may need to modify it for memory management.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  QList<int> items;
  items << 0 << 1 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 13 << 21 << 34 << 55 << 89 << 144;

  QList<int>::iterator i = items.begin();
  while (i != items.end()) {
    if ((*i) % 2 == 0) {
      //  i->DoSomething();  // Not with ints, obviously, but in general.
      i = items.erase(i);  // i points to the next item.
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }

  qDebug() << items;

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! In my case there are some difficulties, because when defining unnecessary items, I must process the list via double-loop (I use indexes: for(i;;) { for(j;;) {} } ), so when I remove item in list, it should be that one of those indexes will point to another element immedeately. If there any identificated field in 'type' of QList, using your solution is rather convenient, but... Never mind, I'll rebuild my source :). Thanks again for attention!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difficulty you are describing, but just to make sure we are clear: you can do processing on the iterator before you erase it, and the iterator automatically points to the next item when erase is called. I will update the code to reflect this.

Comment: In my algorithm (not shown here) I do 2 steps: 1. defining unnecessary elements (source list must stay unmodified while doing that) and 2. remove defined unnecessary elements. In your sample it is possible to process with a single loop, but I can't do the same (twice loop needed). Excuse me, if I didn't understand your opinion.

Comment: Elements of my list doesn't have any info that can identify themselves - so I decide to use iterators for that.