# Is QList/QLinkedList 's iterator permanent?

Tags: c++, qt

In the QLinkedList's insert function, it returns an iterator

```
iterator QLinkedList::insert(iterator before, const T &value)
```

is the returned iterator permanent? Can I find the original `value` I inserted by using the returned iterator? Even after I insert/delete many other items into/from the list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657244/does-qts-qlist-save-iterators-after-containers-modifications

Comment: [`QList`'s not a linked-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602036/qvector-vs-qlist).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation I suppose that the `QList::iterator` is not "permanent", while the `QLinkedList::iterator` is in some cases.

For `QList`

> Multiple iterators can be used on the same list. However, be aware
>   that any non-const function call performed on the QList will render
>   all existing iterators undefined. If you need to keep iterators over a
>   long period of time, we recommend that you use QLinkedList rather than
>   QList.

For `QLinkedList`

> Multiple iterators can be used on the same list. If you add items to
>   the list, existing iterators will remain valid. If you remove items
>   from the list, iterators that point to the removed items will become
>   dangling iterators.

See [QList::iterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist-iterator.html) and [QLinkedList::iterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist-iterator.html)